# Transforming graphs using matrices

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, functions, radicals, transformation

I have the following question:

The graph has of $y=\sqrt{16-x^2}$ has been transformed into the graph of $y=5-2\sqrt{55-6x-x^2}$.
Using the following matrix, I have to apply the transformation and solve for the variables:

$$
T 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & b
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
h\\
k
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I tried to expand the matrix by getting the transformed $x$ and $y$ in terms of the old $x$ and $y$.

$x'=ax+h$

$y'=by+k$

->$x=\frac{1}{a}(x'-h)$

->$y=\frac{1}{b}(y'-k)$

->$y=\sqrt{16-x^2}$ ->$ \frac{1}{b}(y'-k)=\sqrt{16-(\frac{1}{a}(x'-h))^2}$

After expanding:

$ \frac{1}{b}(y'-k) =\sqrt{16-\frac{h^2}{a^2} +\frac{2xh}{a^2} - \frac{x'^2}{a^2}}$

If we compare this equation(only the terms under the square root sign) to the new one they gave, then:

$\sqrt{16-\frac{h^2}{a^2} +\frac{2xh}{a^2} - \frac{x'^2}{a^2}}$ = $\sqrt{55-6x-x^2}$

->$\frac{2h}{a^2} = -6$

-> $16-\frac{h^2}{a^2} = 55$

-> $- \frac{1}{a^2} = -1$

But when I try to solve for $h$ and $a$, it does not add up with the simultaneous equations I got. I think I have done the algebra correctly, I have not found an error(unless I missed it) in my arithmetic, so where am I going wrong?

Comment: How about transform both as implict form

Comment: What is does "implict form" mean?

Comment: I meant, $x^2+y^2=16$ is better, rather than $y=\sqrt{16-x^2}$ to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok, but what is wrong with my method? It seems fine to me.

Comment: You have another degree of freedom: the $b$. You can work it into the square root and *then* try to match terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying to match terms, you should solve for $y'$:

$$
y' = k + b \sqrt{16 - \left(\frac{x'-h}{a}\right)^2} 
$$
Since we want the coefficient of the square root to be $-2$, let's define $b = -2c$ where $c > 0$. We can then insert $c$ into the square root (this is the crucial step that you missed):

\begin{align}
y' &= k - 2c\sqrt{16 - \left(\frac{x'-h}{a}\right)^2} \\
   &= k - 2 \sqrt{16c^2 - \left(\frac{x'-h}{a}\right)^2 c^2} \\
   &= k - 2 \sqrt{16c^2 - \frac{c^2}{a^2}(x'-h)^2} \\
   &= k - 2 \sqrt{16c^2 - \frac{c^2}{a^2}(x'^2 - 2hx' + h^2)} \\
   &= k - 2 \sqrt{16c^2 - \frac{c^2h^2}{a^2} + \frac{2c^2h}{a^2}x' - \frac{c^2}{a^2}x'^2} \\
\end{align}

*Now*, you can start matching:

\begin{align}
   k &= 5 \\
   16c^2 - \frac{c^2h^2}{a^2} &= 55 \\
   \frac{2c^2h}{a^2} &= -6 \\
   \frac{c^2}{a^2} &= 1
\end{align}

These can be easily solved to give $h=-3, c = |a| = 2, b= -4$. If you choose $a=-2$ you'd be flipping the $x$ axis in the other direction, but otherwise, nothing would change.

EDIT: you can see that if you don't introduce the $b$ (or the $c$) above under the square root, the constant term under the square root is going to be 16 minus a square ($h^2/a^2$ in your equation in the question): since the square is always positive, that constant term is going to be *less* than 16. But then there is no way to match it against the desired constant term, which is 55, so you cannot get a solution this way. What getting the $c$ under the square root does is it multiplies that smaller quantity by 4 and gets it up to the desired 55.

Comment: Ok, but why can't I let $b = -2$?

Comment: Because then you cannot find a solution, as you found out.

Comment: Added some more explanation.

Comment: ok, thank you very much!